# Contar la aparición de nombres personales dentro de una columna en un en pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Necesito agregar una columna donde muestre la cantidad de palabras que hay en un dataframe con nombres pero en mi intento solo logro contar el total de palabras en lugar de la cantidad de nombres, he intentado lo siguiente:

```
palabras=[archivos['nombre'].str.split().str.len().sum()]
recuento_palabras= archivos['nombre']
recuento_palabras['palabras'] =palabras 

recuento_palabras
```

Comment: Dani, creo que el código no refleja claro la pregunta: ¿ buscas contar la cantidad de apariciones de cada nombre en un pandas df que contiene nombres en una columna ?, Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la consultas es cómo contar la cantidad de apariciones de cada nombre en una columna que imagino tiene nombres en un pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"nombres":['claudio','maria','pepe','claudio','maria']})

# Asumiendo que SOLAMENTE hay nombres y no otro string en la columna del df:

df['nombres'].value_counts()
```

Comment: lo siento mucho me exprese muy mal al hacer la pregunta jaja, no, me refiero con palabras de forma literal, por ejemplo Maria Isabela que serian dos palabras, o Ana que seria solamente una, necesito crear una nueva columna con la cantidad de palabras que tiene cada nombre

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, solamente tenia que quitar el sum(), perdon por las molestias jaja

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción para  contar la cantidad de apariciones de cada nombre en una columna de un DataFrame cuyos valores son nombres, podría ser la siguiente.
Como ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos una lista de números y queremos saber cuantas veces se repite cada uno de ellos. Para el ejemplo, creamos una lista con números, repetidos algunos de ellos.
Con la función numpy.unique() identificamos valores únicos en la lista  y cuenta las veces que cada uno de ellos se repite, uniéndolos en un único array que denomino 'array_frecuencias'.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Creamos la lista
datos = [7, 3 ,5, 6, 2, 2 ,1 ,1, 5 ,4, 5 ,3 ,3 ,4 ,1 ,1 ,3 ,3 ,4, 4 ,3 ,1 ,5, 4, 3 ,1 ,3 ,2 ,4 ,3 ,4, 5 ,3, 5 ,8, 6, 2,
 3 ,6, 3, 5, 4 ,3, 4, 1, 6, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8, 2, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 5,
 2, 4, 1, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1]

unicos, cuenta = np.unique(datos, return_counts=True)

"""Crea un array (lista de listas). Cada lista contiene una variable única y su frecuencia."""
array_frecuencias = np.array((unicos, cuenta)).T # T 
array_frecuencias
```

En tu caso, 'datos' sería la columna de tu DataFrame 'df['Nombres']

Comment: Si vas a usar docstrings como comentarios recomendaría que hagas uso de su característica de poder escribir en varias líneas.